# building torrent provider website

Tags: spring, libtorrent, torrent

Recently i have been given a project that is torrent provider just like torrentz.eu, thepiratebay etc, where anyone can search what they want to download and then get the download like with the help of torrent.

I don't know the concept behind this, what is the basic requirement and what is the process to make it done. i have searched over Google but didn't find any relevant answer related to my problem.

I just want to know the process and what i really need to do to make it done. technology i will use that is spring framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an Spring specific question but I'll try to help you.

You just need to save the torrent file (a text file with information needed by torrent clients) in a database along with information about the torrent like a representative name, a date and not much more. You could do this using Spring Data JPA for example. This way you won't need SQL knoledges.

If you want a site like torrentz.eu, you will also need to fetch data about the torrent like peers. You can store this also in the database but you will have to update it periodically. To do this, there are APIs like [Bitsnoop](http://bitsnoop.com/info/api.html) that return this kind of information.

Having this, you'll need only some controller mappings to show your home and to let users search torrents given a name (the one that your saved before).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to know that Torrentz and ThePirateBay are 2 different things.
Torrentz is a search engine (like google) that searches for torrent files.
ThePirateBay - in past .torrent files hoster, now a simple Magnet linker.

All you need is a website with a huge .torrent files database.
Also a good hosting in a not online controlled country, so you don't get in trouble just like the most popular torrent website (thepiratebay.se / torrentz.com / kickasstorrents.com ...)
Of course they are still online, but that's just because they have a big fan base that keeps creating mirrors and proxies (https://viralifyblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/19/thepiratebay-proxy-list/)

Finally. I don't recommend creating a torrents website.